# What can I use as a XACML PDP?

Tags: rest, authorization, xacml, alfa, wso2-identity-server

I have an API REST made in node js, and now I'd like to implement some XACML policy. I have been searching and I found that I can use ALFA to make the XACML rules. But I need a PDP for applying the rules. What can I use / how can I implement it?

I have read about WSO2 Identity Server (which I think I can use as a PDP? I'm not sure). It is probably too much for a little project. Any other suggestions? Or is WSO2 IS adecuate?

Comment: You can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590543/xacml-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Wso2 Identity Server as your PDP. Once I had a requirement to secure a Spring Boot rest API through XACML[1]. Anyway, It would be much easier for you to use the Identity Server PDP than implementing one. You have easy beginner samples that you can try out for your use case.[2] There are tools in the identity server that you can use to create the XACML rules.

[1].https://medium.com/@buddhimau/role-based-authorization-for-spring-boot-using-wso2-identity-server-3d74ab307fb9

[2].https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/how-entitlement-management-works-with-rest-api-via-xacml-in-wso2-identity-server-5-3-0-7a60940d040c

Answer (score 3):

The go-to open source implementation of XACML 3.0 nowadays is [AuthZForce](https://github.com/authzforce). In OSS, it's the most up-to-date. In the commercial realm, look into [Axiomatics](https://www.axiomatics.com) (where I worked). They have the most up-to-date PDP and are the authors of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Buddhima Udaranga reply, If you think IS too much for a little project, then you can directly use [balana](https://github.com/wso2/balana), which is the entitlement engine used inside IS. You can refer to [this](https://xacmlinfo.org/2012/12/18/getting-start-with-balana/) for more details. But balana have only java API.